# jquery nested custom scrollbars

Tags: jquery

Is there any jquery plugin for custom scrollbars that support nested scrollbars?

I tried following plugin, it's really good, but it do not support nested scrollbars
http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jscrollpane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) is the best in my opinion

[This demo](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/fullpage_scroll.html) shows that you can use nested scrollbars without a problem.

I've done it before.
There is a slight learning curve to using jscrollpane but it's worth it.